# iText - Creating PDF with one small table and one large table causes the large table to move to new Page instead of splitting

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I'm trying to create a PDF using some data. The data was represented using tables. There are 2 tables.

One table is with 5 rows and 3 columns occupying almost half of the PDF page 1. The other table is having 50 rows and 3 columns which are getting created in a new page (on page 2) instead of continuing after the 1st table on page 1.

How to make the PDF to create the 2nd table under the first table on page 1 and continue to page 2 if the second table has more rows. Should I use PdfPageEvent?

```
public static void createPDF() throws IOException {
        Document document = new Document();
        PdfWriter pdfWriter = null;
        String fileName = "temp.pdf";
        try {
            filePath = tempDirPath + File.separator + fileName;
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
            pdfWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, fos);
            document.open();
            document.add(addTitleTable());
            document.add(addObjsTable());
            document.add(addDateTable());
            document.close();
            pdfWriter.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            document.close();
            pdfWriter.close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your problem can not be reproduced. Can you show us some code so that we can reproduce it? Also: if you are new to iText, why aren't you using iText 7? Why are you using an older version of iText?

Comment: @Pavan as Bruno showed in his answer, code like the lines you added to your question does not explain what you observed. There most likely is something special about the tables generated by `addTitleTable`,`addObjsTable`, and `addDateTable`.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem can not be reproduced.

I have created this example:

```
public void createPdf(String dest) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    Document document = new Document();
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(dest));
    document.open();

    // Table 1
    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(3);
    table.setSpacingAfter(10);
    for(int i = 1; i <= 15; i++){
        table.addCell("Cell " + i);
    }
    document.add(table);

    table = new PdfPTable(3);
    for(int i = 1; i <= 150; i++){
        table.addCell("Cell " + i);
    }
    document.add(table);
    document.close();
}
```

First we create a table with 3 columns and 5 rows (15 cells in total). We define a small spacing after the table of 10 user units.

Then we create a table with 3 columns and 50 rows (150 cells in total).

We add both tables to the document, one after the other. The result looks like this:

[image]

I have followed all the instructions you shared in your question, and the result I obtained shows that your allegation that the second tables starts on a new page is false. The second table starts on the same page as the first table. There's a gap of 10 user units between both tables (as defined in our code). Maybe there is a problem with your code, but please understand that no one can help you if no one can reproduce the problem.